# Tweaking TCP settings for large number of XMPP users

Tags: sockets, tcp, xmpp, ubuntu-12.04

I read that default TCP settings for handling large amount of concurrent users will not be suitable.So i've tweaked some of them, i've added file below.

Problems that i've experiencing now:

- Every 30-40 seconds user connecting are being dropped. Then user automatically reconnects to the user. I've deployed exactly the same server with default tcp setting, and connections are not being dropped.
- When user loses wi-fi connection, and tcp connection is not closed.I reduced keepalive settins, but that doesn't seem to work. User loses wi-fi connection, and he is still perceived as online, however he's definitely offline. Am i applying TCP keepalive settings correctly to solve ungracefully closed TCP connection problem?

`

```
#Increase system file descriptor limit
fs.file-max = 100000

# Discourage Linux from swapping idle processes to disk (default = 60)
vm.swappiness = 10

# Increase ephermeral IP ports
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 10000 65000

# Increase Linux autotuning TCP buffer limits
# Set max to 16MB for 1GE and 32M (33554432) or 54M (56623104) for 10GE
# Don't set tcp_mem itself! Let the kernel scale it based on RAM.
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.core.rmem_default = 16777216
net.core.wmem_default = 16777216
net.core.optmem_max = 40960
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216

# Make room for more TIME_WAIT sockets due to more clients,
# and allow them to be reused if we run out of sockets
# Also increase the max packet backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 50000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 30000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 2000000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10

# Disable TCP slow start on idle connections
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 0

# If your servers talk UDP, also up these limits
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 8192
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 8192

# Disable source routing and redirects
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0

# Log packets with impossible addresses for security
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 10
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using openfire then you need to change Idle Connections Policy settings

Comment: i'm using forked version of eJabberd. What problem will it address?

Comment: I am not sure on eJabberd, I have worked on openfire. Basically you have to make the server to ping the user after fixed interval.If user does not reply then server will make him offline

See the xmpp specification for the same

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html